# Work together on fork of private organization

Tags: git, github

We recently migrated our project from a private svn server to a private github project. We have created an organization with multiple projects. We also have a very specific working environment:

- small core team of very active developers, they have push access to the project
- bigger team of collaborators: they should not have push access since their code quality can't always be trusted and they could mess something up.

The collaborators can now fork the project after we add them to a team, work a bit and make a pull request. So far so good

**The problem**: we also have bigger change requests or experiments and stuff. We therefore want to be able to let a small group create a fork and work together on that (let's say, 2 people work on implementing xml or pdf support or whatever). **How can collaborators collaborate in a private fork?**

What I have tried: fork the project and let someone clone my fork. However, he says he can't push to my fork.
I really want a fast and easy solution. In svn we just created a branch and gave permissions on branch level. But Git can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In svn we just created a branch and gave permissions on branch level. But Git can't do that.

Note that Git does not have any permission system whatsoever. All permission systems you come across when using Git sit on top of Git. [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/) for example is an authorization system that sits on top of Git and SSH and does indeed allow creating branch-level (and even content-based) permissions. While in its simplest form it is just to restrict the public access to your repositories, you can use it for nearly every permission situation you can think of. Obviously this would require a custom server, so if you’re using GitHub, it’s probably not an option for you.

GitHub on the other hand is another system that sits on top of Git and provides a permission system. It’s just a lot simpler and branch level permissions are unfortunately not supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can add people to one of your forks from the Settings -> Collaborators page of that fork.

Comment: I don't have that option on the settings page of that fork. I have Teams, Service hooks, Deploy Keys and Custom tabs.